# Why is my UICollectionView cell not clickable in my swift ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I'm using `UICollectionView` in my swift class, it's placed on my `UIViewController`. I connected the collectionView to the outlet in my code, I set up `delegate` and `datasource` and I see the outcome in my app. Everything works besides the fact that when I click each cell - nothing happens.

My code is as follows:

```
class UsersList: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tview: UICollectionView!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tview.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() //this works
    tview.delegate = self
    tview.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(tview: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    //this does not appear in the console :(
}
```

Is there anything else I could do to see the print msg in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In swift, the parameter name and function name identify a function together.
UICollectionViewDelegate have function

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

but not

`func collectionView(tview: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help, I'm still not able to display any message while clicking cells... I thought it might be caused by the fact that I didn't put the `override` word before the `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` but then when I did that I got a message that `Method does not override any method from its superclass`... Is there anything else I might miss?

Comment: UICollectionViewDelegate is a protocol, there is no need to add `override` keywords. You can check the uicollectionView's `allowsSelection` , it should be true.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing all of your UIGestures from the view then test to see if the UICollectionView Cells are able to be interacted with normally.

In my case, I had to remove the lines:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

For some reason this was getting in the way of being able to click on my cells.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to set the `UICollectionView`'s delegate. For example, in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

This is necessary or the delegate methods will not be called!

Comment: Hi Chloe! Can you please add an explanation as to why that was the solution? Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure the user interaction is enabled in storyboard

Comment: It is enabled, so it must be something else :(

Comment: another possible issue is you set the tview.delegate = self, tview.dataSource = self in viewWillAppear, please do this in viewdidload! Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

I had to change scroll direction from vertical to horizontal in storyboard and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that isUserInteractionEnabled was false for the parent view of the collectionView. I had taken the code for the parent view from somewhere else where evidently that had been the right thing to do. But not here... Sigh...